# Update application badge once a day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

This is the code I have and I it puts the date in a application badge. I was wondering how to reload this number everyday without entering the app to reload it. Thanks in advance!

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSInteger day = [comp day];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = day;
```

Comment: You could you push notifications...

Comment: Yes - push notifications - here's a relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153631/increment-the-push-notification-badge-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively easy way would be to put the code that sets the badge in the background. You can use `[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler]` or a related call for this purpose. The only problem is that there's a 10 minute limit for such execution. Having said that, there are tricks that can be used to circumvent that limit. Here is an excellent thread that discusses this topic: [Run app for more than 10 minutes in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738488/run-app-for-more-than-10-minutes-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

I have following code :

```
NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:3600*24];
notification.fireDate = fireTime;
notification.alertBody = @"Your Message!";
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

If you are testing on simulator then probably that is the reason why you are not getting the output. Test it on device and see whether is it working .