# urban airship badge number iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have been working with urban airship push notification service for iOS for many times , It works , but in this last time I can't get the badge number when I receive  the notification in iOS7 .

I use the normal web form for sending the notification alert and set the budge number as 1 as I always do .. but no budge appear , any body know why?

And how can I make that number increment automatically ? is it done by set the budge as +1?

Comment: Show all the code where you increment the badge. Are you using `UIApplication`'s `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property?

Comment: @Aaron No I just used the urban interface for assign the budge number , I was get that number before but now I don't and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Application badge count is an OS level function on Apple's side. Meaning, if you are sending "1", "+1", or "auto" (For Urban Airship's payload), then it should appear if you have that feature enabled on your device settings.

This is explained a little bit further here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3576

Essentially you will need to navigate to Settings > Notification Center >  to then enable badge app icons for your app.

Comment: I checked that , it's set on  but still can't get the badge number

Comment: Interesting.. have you registered for badge numbers in your application?

http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios_features.html#automatic-integration

EG:
 [UAPush shared].notificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert);
    [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotifications];

Answer (score 0):

- Did you check whether the badge notification is switched on for the application in the device?

[image]

- The values do not increment, you will have to maintain the total number in the server and send it through the payload. So, if you are having 9 unread emails, you will have to send 9 in the payload as the badge number
  See here:[Increment the Push notification Badge iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153631/increment-the-push-notification-badge-iphone)

Comment: I checked the setting it's on but still can't get the badge

Comment: Urban Airship has it's own record of the user's Badge count, so they allow you to use +1 in the payload

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure when you used the UIApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes method that you specified badge number notifications as an option?

Here's the Urban Airship way of doing it:

```
UAPush* push = [UAPush shared];    
[push setNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: could you give a detail for that? I don't do anything in this method

Comment: @Twinkle I edited my answer to add some code for this.

Comment: Yes , I did that @SomeGuy