# No sound when sending push notifications through Parse

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

for whatever reason I cannot get my push notifications to make the default sound nor update the badge number when I receive them. Here's my code below. Do you think it's something wrong with my code? Or is there a configuration issue that I'm not aware of? Thanks for your help!

```
            PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
            [pushQuery whereKey:@"installationUser" containedIn:recipients];

            // Send push notification to our query
            PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
            [push setQuery:pushQuery];
            NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  message, @"alert",
                                  @"Increment", @"badge",
                                  nil];


            [push setData:data];
            [push setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ sent you a photo!", currentUser.username]];


            [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if(!error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Push notification sent!");
                }
            }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same was happening to me, but i using the PHP SDK and the correct way to send this is in this form. In the $data you need to write the things you are sending to the NSDictionary userinfo.

```
    $data = array("alert" => "Your message", "badge" => "Increment", "sound" => "default");

$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo("deviceToken", $devicetoken);

ParsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $query,
  "data" => $data
));
```

Comment: Confirmed, you need specify key "sound" to value "default" to play the default the sound.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
NSDictionary *data = @{
                       @"badge": @"Increment",
                       @"alert": message,
                       @"sound": @"default"
                       };
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with push notifications, not with Parse, not including the sound key/value in the push payload will make the push silent. Try adding the sound with some random value to the dictionary like below and try it out. Also, there's a nicer/cleaner way to create an NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *data = @{
                       @"badge": @"Increment",
                       @"alert": message,
                       @"sound": @"nothing"
                      };
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response Mike. Unfortunately this neither creates generates a sound nor updates my badge. Would you happen to know what else could be the issue?

Comment: check her for incrementing the badge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153631/increment-the-push-notification-badge-iphone. Referring to the sound, have you tried dropping in a test .wav file and putting that there. Also, dumb question I know, but is the phone on vibrate?

Comment: yes I did both those things and for whatever reason there's no sound or badge being updated. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: Do you get the notification?

Comment: yes I get the notification, but there is no sound and no badge.

Comment: Try @1 for the badge and tell me if the badge updates

Comment: Are you testing this with the app open or backgrounded?

Comment: I've tested for both and they both give me a push notification but no sound and no badge update.

Comment: NSLog the push notification info in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: It doesn't appear that function is being called. However, I did try sending a push notification directly through the parse server and the notification does come with a sound. My guess is that this would mean I'm doing something wrong when sending the actual push notification in my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Parse so I can't help there.