# No sound in Parse push notification for ios8

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, ios8, audio

I'm having as issue with Push Notification to iOS8 device. Everything works fine, but the push is not ringing, only appears on the screen.
I am sending normal pushes via dashboard, in which sound is enabled by default. I tested on iPhone4 (iOS 7.1.2), iPhone5 (iOS 7.0.4), it works fine, but there is no sound on iPhone with iOS 8.
Thanks

edit:

1) We have already modified our code to handle changes push notification registration for ios8. Below is the code snippet:

`// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }`

2) Changing any and all configuration settings doesn't helped either, nor does restarting the device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No sound when sending push notifications through Parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452560/no-sound-when-sending-push-notifications-through-parse)

Answer (score 8):

Seems like you need this in the request JSON: `"sound": "default"`. Blank used to work, but now needs "default" to use the default sound.

Answer (score 0):

The push register method is changed in iOS 8.Check following possibilities..

1)Check whether you register push notification with sound as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086599/why-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-called/26115072#26115072).

2)Another possibility is sound can be switched off in notification centre.Check in settings-->notification centre-->click on the app and enable sound.

Comment: Please see our edits. We are following Parse recommendations: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/existing