# No Sound in ios 8 Parse push

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

This is weird, after updating my app to support iOS 8 push notifications sent through Parse (using the Parse dashboard) the push notifications wont make any sound.

I found this duplicatie on Stackoverflow but the answer posted wasn't working for me: [No sound in Parse push notification for ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424478/no-sound-in-parse-push-notification-for-ios8)

- I already checked the notification center and messages and sounds are enabled.
- Created a new clean build of the app
- Checked if other push messages make sounds on the app
- Used the Parse rest api and set the sound to default.

None of the things I tried worked.

Updated my app using the Parse code:

```
// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

} else {
    // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

EDIT: I found an excisting bug report on Facebook dev: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/719233564823090/

Comment: I'm having the same issue. All my apps previous to iOS 8 that are published already aren't activating the UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound when called.

Comment: There is a fix available in the next SDK update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send your push notifications in JSON format rather than the text format in the web console like so:

```
  {"aps":{"alert":"This is a Test","sound":"default"}}
```

It's a workaround until Parse fixes this bug.