# didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying push notifications and want to increase the badge number but

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

is not called in inactive state or background state.

I'm currently working in iOS 9 and Xcode 7.3.

Comment: In inactive state or back ground state you do not have the control over your App's push notification, so it wont get called until you open the app by tapping on the notification from the notification list of device.

Comment: plz read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929869/push-notification-not-receiving-in-background-ios/36934771#36934771

Comment: @Janmenjaya then how would the badge no would increase.. if we try from the api end they can not keep a record for no of notifications sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check once are you enabled or not

[image]

there after the method is called

> didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

at the same time check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929869/push-notification-not-receiving-in-background-ios/36934771#36934771) link also

Answer (score 0):

In your notification payload you have to send `"content-available":1`

Also, this blog post will help you. http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/