# Control app badge count

Tags: ios, push-notification, badge

Server is sending the `badge` count in **push notification**, but if app is in background I want to call a service and display the `badge` count according to the response of that service.

It is possible ignore the `badge` count came in push from and server and show our desired badge count.

Comment: you can receive  push notification when your app in background.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929869/push-notification-not-receiving-in-background-ios/36934771#36934771

Answer (score 0):

To receive a push notification when your app is in the background you need to update the Capabilities of your Target in `Xcode` and add Background Modes...Remote Notifications. You must then add the key content-available to the payload and set to 1. This will trigger `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` See Documentation [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application).

Comment: I already did that. I want to know is there any way to ignore the badge count coming in push. I want to show my custom count , instead of count coming in push notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can update badge count when app goes to background like below.
  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5; //You can update custom count

If you want to clear the PN or update the count,

You can use Silent push notification concept.

Comment: When app is in background and it receive push notification with a badge count of 10 but when I call a service and response of that service is 5 badge count. User first see 10 and then 5 badge count. That is the issue. How to fix that ?