# How to receive push notification from APNs while the app is terminated/Not working in background or foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

APNs is used in the application with the deployment target set to `8.0`. In my application I need to perform some operations in order to determine whether to generate local notification and show it to the user on that moment or not.

When the payload is sent to APNs to generate push notification, application receives push notification whether its in Background or Foreground state and following method gets called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Where app generates a local notification.

The problem is that when the application is Terminated/Closed completely/Does not appear in tabs, app does not receive push notification.

- Development certificates are fine because its working in
  Background/Foreground state.
- Background Mode in `Capabilities` is `ON` with `Background Fetch`, `Remote notifications` checked
- `Push Notifications` is `ON` in `Capabilities`
- The Payload contains `aps` which contains `"content-avilable" : 1` and other data.
- The Payload does not contain `alert`, `badge` or `sound` parameters

Another confusion here is that I have tried using the auto generated notification way too. Where payload contains `alert`, `badge` and `sound` which generates a auto generated push notification even if the application is terminated.

Other applications like `WhatsApp` and `GMail` generates notification while the app is terminated.

So the question is how to implement this feature in my application?

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929869/push-notification-not-receiving-in-background-ios/36934771#36934771

Comment: @balkaran singh, thanks for your answer but it is not useful to me as the payload will auto generate a notification and in my application we need to manage notification locally.