# Notification not displayed with action buttons when app is killed ios

Tags: ios, xcode, unnotificationrequest

I've done following code to display action buttons while notification comes using one signal. But when app is killed notification is not coming. It's working properly in background/foreground mode. But when app is not in tray even notification stop coming. Without action buttons it's working perfectly.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
center.delegate = self;
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
 {
     if( !error ) {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

         NSLog( @"Push registration success." );

     } else {
         NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );

}];

UNNotificationCategory *modifyCategory = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:CYLInviteCategoryIdentifier actions:@[] intentIdentifiers:@[] options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];

UNNotificationAction* snoozeAction = [UNNotificationAction
                                          actionWithIdentifier:@"ACCEPT_ACTION"
                                          title:@"Accept"
                                          options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];

UNNotificationAction* stopAction = [UNNotificationAction
                                        actionWithIdentifier:@"DECLINE_ACTION"
                                        title:@"Decline"
                                        options:UNNotificationActionOptionDestructive];

UNNotificationCategory* actionCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
                                               categoryWithIdentifier:@"INCOMING_CALL"
                                               actions:@[snoozeAction, stopAction]
                                               intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                               options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];

[center setNotificationCategories:[NSSet setWithObjects: modifyCategory, actionCategory,
                                       nil]];
```

Comment: please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929869/push-notification-not-receiving-in-background-ios/36934771#36934771

Comment: you need to add "content-available" :1 in your push notification payload

Comment: @balkaransingh I've set content-available:1 in my payload. But still notification is not coming because of action buttons. Can action buttons be displayed in app killed mode or not?

Comment: registerForRemoteNotifications after the setNotificationCategories. then try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two way to achieve this action handling in Push Notification.
1) Is simple register your UNUserNotificationCenter which you are currently using but you are facing issues with action button not showing in killed mode.

So please check your **payload user info dictionary** identifier & category with your configuration which you shared.

Following is my code please check this Swift code.

```
private func setNotificationCategories() {

let likeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "like", title: "Like", options: [])
let replyAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "reply", title: "Reply", options: [])
let archiveAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "archive", title: "Archive", options: [])
let  ccommentAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "comment", title: "Comment", options: [])


let localCat =  UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "category", actions: [likeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

let customCat =  UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "recipe", actions: [likeAction,ccommentAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

let emailCat =  UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "email", actions: [replyAction, archiveAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([localCat, 

customCat, emailCat])
}
```

And I Updated your code please check this

```
UNNotificationCategory *modifyCategory = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:CYLInviteCategoryIdentifier actions:@[] intentIdentifiers:@[] options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];

UNNotificationAction* snoozeAction = [UNNotificationAction
                                          actionWithIdentifier:@"ACCEPT_ACTION"
                                          title:@"Accept"
                                          options:[]];

UNNotificationAction* stopAction = [UNNotificationAction
                                        actionWithIdentifier:@"DECLINE_ACTION"
                                        title:@"Decline"
                                        options:[]];

UNNotificationCategory* actionCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
                                               categoryWithIdentifier:@"INCOMING_CALL"
                                               actions:@[snoozeAction, stopAction]
                                               intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                               options:[]];



[center setNotificationCategories:[NSSet setWithObjects: modifyCategory, actionCategory,
                                       nil]];
```

change is just don't set option.

2)Use Notification extension You can design attractive push notification. for that, I suggest prefered this blog [iOS Remote Push Notifications](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/learn-master-%EF%B8%8F-ios-remote-push-notifications-in-2018-in-under-10-minutes-825ca6bee092)