# iOS app doesn't receive background push notifications from Firebase

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get push notifications working in a Cordova app I'm working on. They work perfectly in the Android app and they work perfectly in the iOS app when it's in the foreground, but I don't receive any notifications when the app is in the background or terminated.

I have the "Push Notifications" and "Background Modes - Remote notifications" capabilities enabled:

[image: xcode capabilities]

And I'm 100% sure the server has the device token (since push notifications are working in the foreground, and I can see it in the database).

This is how I'm sending the push notification using the [firebase-admin node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin):

```
await firebase.messaging().send({
  token: userDeviceToken,
  data: {foo: 'bar'},
  notification: {
    title: 'This is a notification title',
    body: 'This is a notification body',
  },
});
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

If I launch the app or bring it to the foreground after it was supposed to receive a notification, it acts like it received an in-app notification. This happens even if I wait several minutes after the notification was sent before launching the app.

Answer (score 0):

Check the payload structure you received in the app while foreground. Normally it's different compared to Android. The iOS payload structure should be :

```
{
   "aps" : {
     "alert" : {
       "body" : "great match!",
       "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
     },
     "badge" : 1,
   },
   "Custom_Data" : "Game level name"
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot receive remote notifications when the app is terminated. You may want to show a local notification telling the user that he cannot receive notifications anymore when the app is terminated.

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs for this? I've added terminated PNs to iOS apps in the past. Is this a recent change? Wouldn't that break all sorts of apps that depend on receiving notifications when they're not running (like email or text messages)?

Comment: You can receive remote notification when the app is in background but not when it is terminated.

However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc

Comment: You might also want to set the priority as high as well.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message_options